# Exibir elementos um por um com .each jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, pessoal. Eu estou tendo problemas com o .each do jQuery. Eu tenho um xml assim:

```
<dados>
<usuarios>
    <usuario id="1">
        <login>usuario12</login>
        <senha>21</senha>
    </usuario>
    <usuario id="2">
        <login>usuario23</login>
        <senha>23</senha>
    </usuario>
</usuarios>
```

e estou tentando ler ele assim com jQuery:

```
$(xml).find("usuarios").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).find("usuario").text());
});
```

porém o console me mostra assim:

> usuario1212usuario2323

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: O que esperavas receber na consola?

Comment: Eu esperava receber algo como um objeto "{login: user, senha: pswd}", entende?

Comment: Ok, não é isso que a resposta que marcaste como aceite te dá, mas imagino que conseguiste fazer o resto.

Comment: Na verdade com o código da resposta eu consegui pegar o objeto login e o objeto senha separadamente. Antes eu estava obtendo apenas uma string corrida com toda a informação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deu .find por `usuarios`, mas você só tem 1 `usuarios`. Experimente colocar apenas `usuario`, desse jeito:

```js
var xml = '<dados><usuarios><usuario id="1"><login>usuario12</login><senha>21</senha></usuario><usuario id="2"><login>usuario23</login>        <senha>23</senha></usuario></usuarios>';

$(xml).find('usuario').each(function () {
  console.log("id:" + $(this).attr('id'));
  console.log("login:" + $(this).find('login').text());
  console.log("senha:" + $(this).find('senha').text());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay, é isso mesmo! Obrigado!